# Elastic Beanstalk leader_only at files level

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, devops

I wanted to know how can I define `leader_only` at files level, if I have to create that file on the leader only. Consider the following code, for example:

```
files:
 "/etc/cron.d/mycron":
   mode: "000644"
   owner: root
   group: root
   content: |

      #to keep the segments current.


commands:
  remove_old_cron:
    command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/*.bak"
```

What I know from the documentation is I can only define `leader_only: true` at  `container_commands` level, consider this for example on the [docs page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands-snippet):

```
container_commands:
  collectstatic:
    command: "django-admin.py collectstatic --noinput"
  01syncdb:
    command: "django-admin.py syncdb --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  02migrate:
    command: "django-admin.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
  99customize:
    command: "scripts/customize.sh"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to work around the given circumstances since the commands are executed after files section, create a `template` that will be renamed only for the leader:

```
files:
  "/tmp/mycron.template":
  mode: "000644"
  owner: root
  group: root
  content: |
    #to keep the segments current.

container_commands:
  enable_cron:
    command: "mv /tmp/mycron.template /etc/cron.d/mycron"
    leader_only: true
```

Comment: Yup! I did the similar thing after getting no immediate response over here.. This works anyways. So, thumbs up!